# c# WPF Pagination

Tags: c#, canvas, pagination, drawing

I developed an application that allows drawings of windows and doors. All of these drawings are made within canvas control.
What I want to do is for the user to see all the drawings in summary page form when they press the report button after completing the drawings. I've put an example image below.

Is there any documentation, tutorial etc. that you can share regarding such a paging implementation?

There are such articles on the CodeProject site, but they are made for datagrid control.
Would it be right for me to do it within the datagrid control?

Sample
[image]